# Trigger woocommerce_payment_complete when creating order manually

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a hook to woocommerce_payment_complete, in which I send the order to the distributor. This is working fine.
Now, since I'm also selling through 3rd party marketplace, sometimes I want to create an order form the admin panel, and I expect the woocommerce_payment_complete hook to be triggered by setting the order status to 'Processing' but it's not.
Is there any way to trigger this hook by creating an order manually?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using some code for the hook that is already working, it could be useful to include it in your question. Why do you want to use `woocommerce_payment_complete` hook for an order created manually *with a 'processing' status*? This looks very strange without knowing what this hook is doing exactly.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec. the hook sends the order items to a distributor. I'm already using the woocomerce_payment_complete when a user creates an order and pays for it, that is working perfectly. But since now I'm getting orders from outside the website I want to enter them manually and I need the same logic in the woocomerce_payment_complete hook. I tought the same hook would work since I'm setting the order to processing status but it  is not called

Comment: That is normal, as this hook is explicitly called when the order is complete. So that's why I ask for you `woocommerce_payment_complete` hooked function code. Without it I can't make a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to set 'processing' for admin orders. `action_woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta` is used to detect the order update.

```
// define the woocommerce_admin_order_actions_end callback 
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_actions_end( $order_id ) { 
    global $woocommerce;
    if (!$order_id)
        return;
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);

    $order_status = $order->get_status();
    if ($order_status != "failed") {
        $order->update_status('processing');
    }
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'action_woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_actions_end', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Hi, that's not what I want to do. I can manually set the order status to 'Processing'. What I want is the hook 'woocommerce_payment_complete' to run when I do that.